# VBA show row if value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select only rows with the value unchecked but I am getting an error  due to type mismatch. Please advise

```
Sub Hide_Rows()

    If Range("D3:F100").Value = "Checked" Then
        Rows("3:100").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("D3:F100").Value = "Unchecked" Then
        Rows("3:").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are testing 3 cells per row, if any are checked you want it hidden or if all are checked?

Comment: Please provide some more details, such as the exact error message and a screendump of the sheet containing the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test an array of values to one value:

> `If Range("D3:F100").Value = "Checked" Then`

will always error.  You need to loop and check each value individually:

This will un-hide the row if any of the values in Columns D,E,F are `Unchecked`  All others will be hidden.

```
Sub Hide_Rows()


ActiveSheet.Range("3:100").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Dim i As Long
For i = 3 To 100
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 4 To 6
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j) = "Unchecked" Then
            Dim UnRng As Range
            If UnRng Is Nothing Then
                Set UnRng = ActiveSheet.Rows(i)
            Else
                Set UnRng = Union(UnRng, ActiveSheet.Rows(i))
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

UnRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I realised I'm trying to do the operation backwards. I only want to show the rows if they are "unchecked" so the default is hidden. So hmmm. I'll give it a go. Awesome to get the help :)

Comment: Awesome thank you. My first VBA project worked. Thank you for helping me with it.